# Pyautogui Quits / throws Exception when Remote Desktop is Minimized

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, python, gui

I'm running a remote desktop connection that is running PyAutoGUI. When I minimize the remote desktop Window, pyautogui automatically throws an exception relating to the fail safe (which is when you move the mouse cursor to the top right corner of the screen).

I think this is some optimization Windows is doing to stop calculating the screen pixels when the remote desktop window is minimized, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to disable this optimization so that pyautogui will continue running even when the remote desktop connection is minimized?